# brackets, install extension failed

Tags: adobe-brackets

[image]

I download `brackets icons` zip and drop it to brackets to install it.

But brackets give me this error.

and this:

[image]

I' m in China.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking for the same extension in the extensions manager *search* field?
Try installing some other extension and install it so you can see if the extension you downloaded is not ok.

I checked right now and the extensions registry works fine.

or you can do it manually:

```
Help -> Show Extensions Folder
```

You should see a *user* folder. Unpack your zip file there and reload Brackets.